# Why does it take Radiant CMS so long to update after changes are saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radiant

I've been looking for some sort of cachine mechanism but can't find one. Anyone know why it takes so long to see changes after they are saved in the CMS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RadiantCMS caches content for 5 minutes.](http://radiantcms.org/overview/)

Comment: Is there a polite way to truncate that time?